# Team Foundation Server: Move Root-Level Project

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to clean up our work-site Team Foundation Server 2010 defaultcollection.

Unfortunately we originally set it up with a whole bunch of projects at the root level of the defaultcollection.

Now we want to clean it up by moving a bunch of those projects into a root-level archive directory, while preserving the history of the projects.

This is proving extremely difficult. I've read a bunch of stuff online and run some trials, but I'm still having issues.

Part of the problem is that projects at the root level seem to be "immune" to a bunch of "normal" actions you can perform on projects in general, such as the Move command (which is greyed-out).

If I try to use the command line to perform the move like this:

```
tf.exe move $/TestProj $/Archive/TestProj/
```

I get:

```
TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/Test. Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.
```

So I figured I'd move the contents like this:

```
tf.exe move $/TestProj/* $/Archive/TestProj/
```

That worked, and history was preserved, but then when I deleted the original project like this:

```
TFSDeleteProject.exe /collection:MYSERVER\DefaultCollection TestProj /force
```

History was lost!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those aren't "root level projects". Those are "Team Projects". There's a lot more to a team project than just source control, so, no, you can't do the same things with a "team project folder" as you could with a lower-level folder.

TFS does not use the term "project" the same way that SourceSafe did. In SS, "project" meant pretty much the same thing as "folder".

Comment: Right, OK, so is there a way to move "Team Projects"? It seems the history of items once residing in the Team Project is tied not to the items themselves but to the Team Project, meaning that "cleaning up" Team Projects in my sense of the term is synonymous with destroying it...?

Comment: You can rearrange folders under the team projects, but  you can't rename them or move them. Remember, a team project is "a root source control folder plus a lot more".

Comment: OK, please confirm that the history of an item that originally resided in a Team Project belongs to the Team Project permanently. Or rather, if that item was later branched or moved, the history of that item (as long as it resided in the Team Project) "belongs" to the Team Project and cannot be separated from it. Removing the Team Project destroys the history of that item, or at least the history for the duration of time that the item resided in the the project. Right? (Thanks!)

Comment: The history of the item belongs with the item, not with the the team project.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not appear to be the case, at least for us. I've tried twice with two "sacrificial" Team Projects. I move the contents of the Team Project into the archive. History still exists for them. Then I use TFSDeleteProject to delete the Team Project, and the history is instantly gone from the items in the archive. Mind you, we are using the /force switch on TFSDeleteProject to get around the annoying SharePoint site nag...

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you could safely delete team projects - you can't delete them if they were ever interesting. Move the contents and set the source control folder read-only. Team Projects are meant to be permanent, important things.  They are not just folders.

Comment: Then by the sounds of it, there's no way to correct our early-on mistake in laying out the structure. I guess we'll just have to live with it. Can I ask one final question? It looks like if we delete a Team Project, that the history that is lost is only up to the point when the items in the project were branched or moved elsewhere? In other words the history of those items in their new location is preserved?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that. I just know deleting team projects is something to not do.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the /keephistory option... as I understand it, that is supposed to allow you to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: There does not appear to be any such option.